# How to create a sidebar with Firefox WebExtensions?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to migrate an extension and yes, I know that I can not add more than one button per [WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) to the browser interface, but I would like to know if it is possible to create a sidebar somehow. I know that I can manipulate the DOM of the site, but in some cases (e.g. Facebook) it is difficult due to their css, and I need to make sure that my sidebar is visible from any Website where the user wants to use it to see some stats.

Do you know a way for creating a pseudo-sidear (DOM), no matter the site?

PS: Do you think a sidebar (browser UI) will be available in the future?

Any idea is welcome,

Comment: https://bugzil.la/1208596, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM

Comment: @DanielHerr, Your suggestion to use Shadow DOM is not helpful here. This is a Firefox WebExtensions question. [Firefox does not support Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Shadow_DOM#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @Makyen No, but it should eventually, which is asked.

Comment: @DanielHerr, Which makes it useless for this question, now. In addition, the Shadow DOM is not a sidebar. You could make a pseudo-sidebar using a Shadow DOM, but it is not a sidebar. Firefox has supported an *official* sidebar for years (not added to content DOM). It has been available to add-ons, or the user can specify that bookmarks/history (links, or the bookmark/histiry UI) open in a sidebar (e.g. press ctrl-B to have the bookmarks list open in the sidebar).  In a Firefox context, the second is question is asking for *official* ways that a sidebar would be supported, not DOM manipulation.

Comment: Please [edit] your question. You are asking two questions. One in the title, then "Do you think a sidebar will be available in the future?". The latter question is opinion based. The question in the title, "How to create a sidebar" is too broad as there are many ways to create a pseudo-sidebar by adding content to every webpage's DOM. If you are asking about an *official* sidebar (completely separate from webpage DOM) as is possible with other types of Firefox add-on, then at least the title question is answerable, but needs to explicitly state that you are looking for an *official* sidebar.

Comment: Asking directly: Are you specifically asking only about a sidebar similar to what can be created with the Add-on SDK [`ui/sidebar`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar), which is completely separate from the content of the webpage, persists across page re-loads, etc.? Are you specifically excluding asking about how to create a pseudo-sidebar which is created by manipulating the DOM of every webpage? I believe this is what you are asking about, but given the WebExtension context, this needs to be crystal clear that you *not* asking DOM based sidebars.

Comment: @Makyen I updated the question. You got the idea, feel free to edit it if you think is not clear enogh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a sidebar, it's [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar).

1. First you need to edit your manifest.json, to add the "[sidebar-action"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/sidebar_action).

   ```
   "sidebar_action": {   
       "default_icon": {
           "16": "button/geo-16.png",
           "32": "button/geo-32.png"
       },  
       "default_title": "My sidebar", 
       "default_panel": "sidebar/sidebar.html" 
   }
   ```
2. Create the sidebar.html with its scripts and CSS if needed.

You have an example webextension [here](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/annotate-page), on Github to learn how to create a sidebar. It's called "*annotate-page*".

You can call your sidebar with ***[a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Sidebars)***

```
 sidebarAction.getPanel()
```

or ***a keyboard shortcut***, so you can use your extension button to call a browser-action, as I think you asked for this, as you said "*I know that I can not add more than one button per WebExtension*".

You have only one action when clicking the toolbar button, ***only if*** you don't use a ***popup*** that will shows other buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Should be landing soon, in Firefox 54 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1208596